# @parcel/transformer-babel: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to learn how to use Typescript with React. I have declared the App component as follows:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

type AppState = {
  apiResponse: string;
};

export default class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  testApi() {
    const url = "http://localhost:9000/testApi";
    const body = {};

    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ apiResponse: data }));
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.testApi();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>{this.state.apiResponse}</h1>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" (4:5)
  3 | 
> 4 | type AppState = {
>   |     ^
  5 |   apiResponse: string;
  6 | };
```

Is there something wrong with my understanding of the syntax or is there something wrong with my Parcel dependency?

Comment: Your typescript [is well formed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQokscA3nAMImQB2W38AXzhES5Snhi06dGAE8wWOAEEwYAMoxkMRQF5WdOCjDBsqHqiwAuOKhhRg3AOb0B9OlgAeTeABMsBZABXABt4XGC0dBUwOE9tbh90TnAIXn4AHhYBABplVQ0tLAA+fUNtWxVgAAoASlLDOFxU2zhAqGC4PTIACxgYMEsAekHgiFxkYO6IW0sATgAGRcHymEqpBsbm+AAjCB9ZTtZXaQ2CLBhcbqq24JqDDbgAOhhuviqqylQ6nRLP57jancHk8Xm8qj4tMhviUXsBUI8LDACtoqmxkMZTOYrHAIZo4AIajV6IYBCdNik0jAAOrAYLBACyEEC-Fq9TK3Th-wqxlqxPxZMoCSwUFZLHuhkoMDa3DgVXFDXSRXlG3S3QAjEUWLD4bZCo90SYsGZmlgBOlBuqlcDzVaGkT7qSBEA)

Comment: Don't know much about Parcel, but I assume you'll need `@babel/preset-typescript` in your babel config.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out it was something wrong with the parcel dependency. I created the React app with `nano-react-app` originally and just redid it with `create-react-app`. Now everything is working fine.